# Using the for loop in the Module function

Tags: scoping, list-manipulation

Good afternoon, I need some help. I have compiled a function that calculates the flight of the ball, step by step I made an analytical solution first, then a numerical one. But in numerical it is not possible to set the initial data for arrays, Mathematica does not perceive the initial data that I entered, I specified this place. I will be grateful for any help!

```
Padenie[x0_, z0_, \[Alpha]_, v0_, d0_, M0_] := 
 Module[{x = x0, z = z0, \[Alpha]0 = \[Alpha], v01 = v0, M = M0, 
   d = d0},
  (* Рабочее поле *)
  
  
  (* Аналитическое решение *)
   
  g = 9.81;
  \[Xi] = 1;(* Какой-то там коэфициент*)
  
  x1[t_] := x + v01*Cos[\[Alpha]0]*t;
  z1[t_] := z + v01*Sin[\[Alpha]0]*t - (g t^2)/2;
  (* Определение границ для t *)
  q1 = Solve[z1[t] == 0 , t] ;


  
  (*  M - кол-во точек разбиения *)
  
  \[Tau] = q1[[2, 1, 2]]/M ;  (* Шаг сетки*)
  
  (* Создаём массив данных*)
 
                          Error was here
 
  Table[{x10[j7*\[Tau]], z10[j7*\[Tau]], u10[j7*\[Tau]], 
    w10[j7*\[Tau]], V10[j7*\[Tau]]}, {j7, 0, M}];
  (* Начальные условия *)
  u10[0] = x1'[0];
  w10[0] = z1'[0];
  x10[0] = x1[0];
  z10[0] = z1[0];


  (* Расчёты *)
  For[j1 = 0, j1 <= M - 1, j1++,
   
   
   u10[(j1 + 1)*\[Tau]] = 
    u10[j1*\[Tau]] - \[Tau]* \[Xi]* (
      3*u10[j1*\[Tau]]*
       Sqrt[(u10[j1*\[Tau]])^2 + (w10[j1*\[Tau]])^2])/(4 d);
   w10[(j1 + 1)*\[Tau]] = 
    w10[\[Tau]*
       j1] - \[Tau]*(g + \[Xi]*(
         3*w10[j1*\[Tau]]*
          Sqrt[(u10[j1*\[Tau]])^2 + (w10[j1*\[Tau]])^2])/(4 d));
   x10[(j1 + 1)*\[Tau]] = x10[\[Tau]*j1] + \[Tau] *u10[\[Tau]*j1];
   z10[(j1 + 1)*\[Tau]] = z10[\[Tau]*j1] + \[Tau] *w10[\[Tau]*j1];
   
   ];
  
  ]
```

Comment: Mathematica tells me that x[0] z[0] u[0] w[0] are not defined in any way

Comment: From your question it is not very clear, what did you intend to achieve with the code. It looks to be contradictory to the whole Mathematica paradigm. In addition, it contains several errors. I will first point them out and after that write about the whole statement.l It will take several comments. 1. The statement `Table` is "flying in the air". It does not work and it is not clear, what you intend it for. 2. The statement like `u10[0] = x1'[0]` is incorrect, since `x1[0]` is not a function, but a number. Its derivative is zero. Thus, `x1'[0]` is equal to zero. Instead, you should

Comment: Continuation: either calculate this derivative analytically (easy in this case) or make the following construct `u10[0] = x1'[t]/.t->0`. That is, first calculate the derivative and then put time equal to zero. 3. Minor comment: the very last two semicolons in the loop are not needed. Now concerning the paradigm. The philosophy behind Mathematica is that the user should not solve the problems the way you did it in the second part of your solution. Mathematica contains a lot of routines where this work has already been performed for you,

Comment: Continuation: and you only need to correctly choose the routine you need and correctly select its options. After that, your problem will be solved in one line of code. In particular, in your case, the first part of your solution is good in the Mathematica spirit, while the second is not needed. In more complex cases, if the solution of the equation of motion is not that simple, look at the function `NDSolve` (Menu/Help/WolframDocumentation/NDSolve).

Comment: Continuation: In general, it is advised to avoid loops in Mathematica and only use them, when their use is inevitable. Such cases are, however, rare. The most powerful tool to use instead which plays in Mathematica a role somewhat close to that of loops is  `Table`.

Comment: Hello, thank you for trying to understand my problem. I corrected my mistake, it was just to denote the initial conditions not so x[0]=...., but so x[0.]=....

Comment: In fact, I was solving a computational fluid dynamics problem. And the Mathematica package was used, so it's nice for me to work on it

Comment: As for the paradigms, I completely agree with you, I will still redo this code, because it is no good.

Comment: I was thinking how to write it more rationally, through Pure function and Table, but so far I am limited in time, because I have been correcting my mistakes for a long time :)

Comment: In the initial conditions, I only tried to achieve the assignment of x[0]=x0 , but nothing came out, so I tried the replacement rule/. -> , and differentiating